# While querying my DB and showing results in form of a table, cannot choose other than first

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Currently I am displaying a table on my jsp by querying the mysql DB, I have several buttons that you can do things with this object. There is an update button that you can update current information about the car, there is a rent out car button, and a delete button. I notice that the delete selects the correct ID and deletes it from the correct DB however the update and rent this car button gives you the first instance of the code in the table, so if you want to choose the 5th car down it will always give you the results of the first car. Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

```
 try
  {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carrentalsystem";
   String username="root";
   String password="javatest";
   String query="select * from cardetails";
   Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
   while(rs.next())
   {

    <tr class="tblHeader">
    <td>Rent This car</td>
    <td>Car ID</td>
    <td>Year</td>
    <td>Make</td>
    <td>Model</td>
    <td>Color</td>
    <td>Availability</td>
    <td>Update</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
    <td>
    <form action="rentoutadmin?id=<%=rs.getInt("id")%>" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="User_Name" placeholder="User Name">
                <input id="submit" type="submit">
            </form>

   <br>
    <p> ID: <%=rs.getInt("id")%></p>
    <br>
    <p> Year: <%=rs.getString("Year") %></p>
    <br>
    <p> Make: <%=rs.getString("Make") %></p>
    <br>
    <p> Model: <%=rs.getString("Model") %></p>
    <br>
    <p> Color: <%=rs.getString("Color") %></p>
    <br>
    <p> Availability: <%=rs.getString("Availability") %></p>
    </td>
    <td><%=rs.getInt("id")%></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Year") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Make") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Model") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Color") %></td>
       <td><%=rs.getString("Availability") %></td>
       </td>
        <td><form action="deletecar?id=<%=rs.getInt("id")%>" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="delete">Delete</button>
        </form></td>

         </tr>
```

Comment: I'm only seeing one "button", for delete - have you cropped the code, or is the submit button one of those you mentioned?

Comment: are you sure that this code shows a proper table and the problem is only in buttons ?

Comment: Yes sorry I have the update and the rent out the car as modals which took up alot of space, however the rent out car form is seen above that is what the modal reaches into.

Comment: The code is displaying each instance of the table, however the buttons when clicked give only the first instance, and the servlets are grabing on the first instance.

Comment: After inspecting the page I notice that each instance of the table is getting a new modal created, and when you click the button for whatever reason every modal which is the exact same size and area are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the ID to the actual ID of the button so it knew which instance I was telling it to grab.